# LibreOffice can't compile

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, make

I'm trying to compile LibreOffice, using the instructions [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnLinux). But when I run `make`, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/opt/libreoffice/core/pyuno/Library_pyuno.mk:10: /opt/libreoffice/core/instdir/program/libpyuno.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:282: build] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to source? If so, you might want to ask on StackOverflow which is dedicated to programming and software development. Otherwise if you are just trying to install LibreOffice, all you need is `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install libreoffice`

Comment: It looks like you have a non-default (local) installation of the python development libraries - perhaps that is significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled python 3.7 and installed python 3.8. This made it compile with no errors.